# Reading Dom ID Jquery Method

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(document).on('click', '.table .table_head1 a', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="table_head1">
                <a href="#" id="name">First Name
                </a>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

I want to use the name of the id if I click on th/a but the above code I wrote is not working at all, it even not detecting that I have clicked on it.

(Yes Jquery is also included)

Comment: You are missing a `)` at the end of your script.

Comment: You need to close round bracket of `$(document).on(function(){ /*something*/ });` at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have syntax error by missing `)` at the end, other than that your code is working as expected.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).on('click', '.table .table_head1 a', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   alert($(this).attr('id'));
});

</script>

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="table_head1">
          <a href="#" id="name">First Name
          </a>
        </th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: @user7434123, yes, you are right and that is what I have mentioned in my answer.........thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `e.target.id` or `$(this).attr('id')` to do it in the jQuery way.

You had a syntax error in your code as I pointed out in my comment.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.table .table_head1 a', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert('Vanilla JS: ' + e.target.id);
  alert('JQuery: '+ $(this).attr('id'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="table_head1">
        <a href="#" id="name">First Name
          </a>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes it worked, but can you tell me what's wrong with this method $(this).attr('id') it worked for one of my old code.

Comment: Nothing wrong with that. It is just the jQuery way to do it. I also included it in my answer.